# Android FacebookSDK gives me "is misconfigured for Facebook login"

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have searched for info on the "is misconfigured for Facebook login" error message but have found no working solution. I have set Util.ENABLE_LOG to true but I get no error message in my log at all and so I can not figure out what is causing this.

I am developing with Eclipse on a Mac.

I have generated a hash with the keygen tool.

It seems Eclipse is looking for the debug.keystore in the correct location.

I simply call `facebookSDK.authorize(activity, this);` where activity is my main activity holding a SurfaceView that draws my UI on canvas (its a game like app), and this opens the FacebookSDK login UI just fine and I can log in but it then gives me this "misconfigured" error message (but nothing in the logs).

The callback methods "onComplete, onFacebookError, onError, onCancel" never gets called.

So, Im stuck here! Any ideas to what I can do to figure out what the problem really is?

Thank you

Søren

Comment: authorize is deprecated, the docs on facebook for this are old. better take a look at the examples in the newest android sdk for facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah now I know what the problem was! When you generate the hash you must use "android" as the password, I did not catch that one.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to use this code to get correct hash, instead of command, since it gives different hashes for pc, mac and linux:

```
PackageInfo info;
try {
info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.myname.lolo", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
           MessageDigest md;
md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
md.update(signature.toByteArray());
           //String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
            * String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
           Log.e("hash key", something);
} 
}
catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
}

catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
}
catch (Exception e){
Log.e("exception", e.toString());
}
```

And u can delete this code afterwards